# Speech and prompt work at the same time in javascripy

Tags: javascript

I have the question that can we operate two discrete statements at the same time ? for example I want to create a webpage that when the prompt show up a sentence to get information from users and at the same time can I make the voice which will speak the sentence in that prompt?
Ex : this is my js file and I'm making a page that can get the information about users's family

```
function myFunction() {
  let numberOfMembers = prompt("How many people are there in ur family?");
  for (let i = 0; i < numberOfMembers; i++) {
    let docTen = i + 1;
    responsiveVoice.speak("what is ur member's" + " " + docTen + " " + "first name","UK English Male");
    let membersFirstName = prompt(
      "what is ur member's" + " " + docTen + " " + "first name"
    );
    let membersLastName = prompt("what is urmember's " + " " + docTen + " " + " last name?");
    let membersAge = prompt("how old is ur " + " " + docTen + " " + " member?");

    
    let table = document.getElementById("myTable");
    let row = table.insertRow(-1);
    let cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
    let cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
    let cell3 = row.insertCell(2);
    cell1.innerHTML = membersFirstName;
    cell2.innerHTML = membersLastName;
    cell3.innerHTML = membersAge;
  }
}
function myFunction1() {
  document.getElementById("myTable").deleteRow(-1);
}
```

This code doesn't make the speech and the prompt operate at the same time
I'm verry pleased to see your response

Answer (score -1):

[`responsiveVoice.speak`](https://responsivevoice.org/api/) should speak the text asynchronously (in the background). The issue is that [`window.prompt`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/prompt) blocks the main thread, which prevents ResponsiveVoice from working in the background.

You could wait until the speech is finished, using the `onend` callback, before calling `await`. Here's one approach, using [await](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await):

```js
await new Promise((resolve) => 
  responsiveVoice.speak("what is ur member's" + " " + docTen + " " + "first name","UK English Male",
    {onend: resolve});
let membersFirstName = prompt(
  "what is ur member's" + " " + docTen + " " + "first name"
    );
```

Alternatively, you should build your own interface to replace `prompt`, which creates some DOM to ask the question and waits for an answer.

Comment: These are not async operation so putting them into a promise won't do anything

Comment: @Liam As I understand `responsiveVoice.speak`, it asynchronously voices the speech and then calls the `onend` callback. By constructing a promise that resolves when `onend` gets called, this becomes an async operation which can be `await`ed.

Comment: and how is that "running at the same time"?

Comment: You're right, it's not. It was a workaround because it's not possible to do anything at the same time as `window.prompt`. The only way to do voice and prompt at the same time is the second approach I suggested, replacing `prompt`.

Comment: So the answer to the question is actually,  it's not possible to do anything at the same time as window.prompt then?

Comment: Yes. Hence "The issue is that `window.prompt` blocks the main thread, which prevents `ResponsiveVoice` [or anything] from working in the background." Sorry if the answer was unclear; I'm new!